# GORM creating tables with base class name instead concrete class name

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I Have the following domains in my gorm package:

Domain.groovy

```
package gorm

class Domain {
    String createdBy
    static constraints = {
    }
    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy true
    }

}
```

User.groovy

```
package gorm

class User extends Domain {
    String name

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

I want a table named user with the fields of the base class domain, but instead GROM generate a table whit this specification

```
create table domain
(
    id bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    version bigint not null,
    created_by varchar(255) not null,
    class varchar(255) not null,
    name varchar(255) null
)
```

I'm using mysql driver with grails 2.5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generates the table with the name as `domain` because you are using `tablePerHierarchy true` in your mapping.

Basically, you will get one table where you can set different discriminators for the subclasses.

See here for more information on inheritance strategies: http://docs.grails.org/2.5.x/guide/single.html#GORM
(scroll down to: 7.2.3 Inheritance in GORM)

If you simply want schema-export to generate your table with the name as `user`, then you would need to add the following to your mapping block in the `Domain` class:

`table 'user`'

so the entire mapping block would look like:

```
static mapping = {
    table 'user'
    tablePerHierarchy true
}
```

However, this may not make sense to name the table `user` if you have other classes extend from `Domain`.
(and if you don't plan to have other classes extend from `Domain`, then just add your fields into your `User` domain).

If you want to generate two tables (`Domain` and `User`), then set `tablePerHierachy false`.

Here is a great write-up with examples that may help you decide which way you want to go for your project:

https://sysgears.com/articles/advanced-gorm-features-inheritance-embedded-data-maps-and-lists-storing/

As a side note: I'm not keen on the name `Domain` for a domain class; it is too generic and may get confusing when you are talking about the specific `Domain` class vs domain classes. At least name it `BaseDomain`.

Comment: Nice, I wil generate two tables in this case, thanks.